# OpenCL image2d_t returning wrong values when mapping it back to host

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I am writing a raytracer, and was trying to write the result of the generated image to an image2d_t and then write it to disk by mapping it back to the host.

Problem is, I couldn't make the OpenCL kernel write to the image2d_t and read the result back on the host. The image back on host is a mostly black image with some white dots.

Here is the important part of my host code:

```
cl_image_format rgba_format;
rgba_format.image_channel_order = CL_RGBA;
rgba_format.image_channel_data_type = CL_UNSIGNED_INT8;

outputImage = clCreateImage2D(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
        &rgba_format, width, height, 0, NULL, &err);
if(err < 0) fatalError("failed to create OpenCL image");

err = clSetKernelArg(sampleKernel, 0, sizeof(outputImage), &outputImage);
if(err < 0) fatalError("failed to set kernel argument.");

size_t global_offset[2] = {0, 0};
size_t work_size[2] = {height, width};

int err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, sampleKernel, 2, global_offset,
        work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
if(err < 0) fatalError("failed to enqueue kernel execution.");

clFinish(queue);

// Map the entire output image.
size_t row_pitch;
size_t origin[3] = {0, 0, 0};
size_t region[3] = {width, height, 1};
uint8_t *output = (uint8_t *) clEnqueueMapImage(queue, outputImage,
        CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, origin, region, &row_pitch, NULL, 0, NULL,
        NULL, &err);
if(err < 0) fatalError("failed to map output kernel image.");

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    printf("%u %u %u %u\n", output[i*4], output[i*4 + 1], output[i*4 + 2],
            output[i*4 + 3]);

savePPM(output);
```

My client code:

```
__kernel void sample(__write_only image2d_t out)
{
    int2 coord = (get_global_id(1), get_global_id(0));
    uint4 color = (255, 0, 0, 255);
    write_imageui(out, coord, color);
}
```

The printf() output is:

```
255 255 255 255
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

And the generated image is:
[image]

I know I am probably making a rookie mistake, but I can't figure out what the problem is and I couldn't find anywhere on the internet any guides to make this work.

I am using a MacBook Pro with an Intel Iris Pro Graphics GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. Do not EVER forget to add the type qualifier on OpenCL vectors.

The fixed Kernel is:

```
__kernel void sample(__write_only image2d_t out)
{
    int2 coord = (int2) (get_global_id(1), get_global_id(0));
    uint4 color = (uint4) (255, 0, 0, 255);
    write_imageui(out, coord, color);
}
```

Comment: I was just waiting the 2 days time limit. Thanks for the heads up and the explanation.